# How to change x axis scale on faceted geom point plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with this data set, which provides one observation's value for 3 different statistics, along with columns to represent the greater minimum, maximum, and mean values of the population of that stat.

[image]

I am trying to create a one dimensional "slider plot" in ggplot that place a point's value between the minimum and maximum values for each stat.

I have tried this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = 0)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, color = "black") +
  annotate("segment", 
           x = df$min_value,
           xend = df$max_value,
           y = 0,
           yend = 0,
           size = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = "here")) +
  facet_wrap(~my_stat,
             ncol = 1,
             nrow = 3, 
             scales = "free_x") +
   theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
         axis.line.y = element_blank(), 
         axis.text.y = element_blank()
   )
```

Which produces these plots.

[image]

The problem is that while the plot is unique for each stat, the scale is not unique. How can I alter the code so that the x axis scale for each plot is unique to that statistic, and in turn the data is plotted correctly?

Additionally, would it be possible to plot an image in place of the point? In most cases this could be solved using ggimage(), but given the difference in these slider plots I'm not so sure.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(my_stat = c("a", "b", "c"), value = c(1.7, 2.1, 
3), mean_value = c(2.5, 2, 4), min_value = c(1.5, 1.2, 2.9), 
    max_value = c(3, 2.8, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `annotate` to add you segments. Doing so you add all three segments to each facet. Switch to `geom_segment` and you should be fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = 0)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, color = "black") +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = min_value, xend = max_value,
      y = 0, yend = 0
    ),
    size = 1
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = "here")) +
  facet_wrap(~my_stat,
    ncol = 1,
    nrow = 3,
    scales = "free_x"
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]